# Redirect to www, https and add a trailing slash using .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This is my current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?p=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.*)$ index.php?p=$1&a=$2
```

It works, but I would like to simplify it to avoid unnecessary redirects.

I need to redirect the user to the WWW subdomain, HTTPS protocol and add the trailing slash if needed, with as least as possible redirects.

Can somebody suggest a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce it as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.domain.com [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ https://www.domain.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]    
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/(.+)$ index.php?p=$1&a=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I just tried it and I get an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. I open http://domain.com/ and end up on http://domain.com//